# Create new column with string containing column names based on condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-cleaning, columnsorting

I need to clean up a large datafile (±1300 columns) and store it into a logical data frame. I know it should be possible, but I have no idea how.

So my data only contains 'yes', 'no' or 'n/a' values, but it's the columns they are in that have all the needed information. It's about who you spent time with during your day. Each row is 1 participant. Here is an example:

| Monday.06.00.adult.1 | Monday.06.00.adult.2 | Monday.06.00.adult.3 | Monday.07.00.adult.1 | Monday.07.00.adult.2 | Monday.07.00.adult.3 | Monday.08.00.adult.1 | Monday.08.00.adult.2 | Monday.08.00.adult.3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | yes | n/a | yes | yes | n/a | no | yes | n/a |
| yes | no | no | yes | no | no | yes | yes | yes |

Here you can deduct that participant 1 spends his Monday morning at 6 o'clock with adult 1 and adult 2, and there is no adult 3. Adult 1 leaves at 8, as then his presence is changed to 'no'. For participant 2 we see that his mornings start with only adult 1, and adult 2 and 3 join at 8. I have columns for every hour of every day for a whole week for spending it with 5 adults and 5 children... How I would want my data to look at the end:

| Participant | Day | Hour | SpentWith |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monday | 06 | Adult1, Adult2 |
| 1 | Monday | 07 | Adult1, Adult2 |
| 1 | Monday | 08 | Adult2 |
| 2 | Monday | 06 | Adult1 |
| 2 | Monday | 07 | Adult1 |
| 2 | Monday | 08 | Adult1, Adult2, Adult3 |

Is there any way that I can select (per row) all the 'yes' answers, and then combine their column names if they overlap on the day and hour? (So for participant 1, the 'yes' answers would be in column Monday.06.00.adult.1 and Monday.06.00.adult.2, and I need to be able to extract and then combine 'Adult1' and 'Adult2' and store it into a separate column.

I've tried to collect all column names from the 'yes' answers with

```
names(data)[which(data == "yes", arr.ind=T)[, "col"]]
```

But this provides me with a list where I cannot see which value (column name) belongs to which participant, which makes it impossible to concatenate the right ones.

```
"monday.06.00.adult.1"      "monday.06.00.adult.1"      "monday.06.00.adult.2"      "monday.06.00.adult.2"      "monday.07.00.adult.1"      "monday.07.00.adult.2"      "monday.07.00.adult.2".     "monday.07.00.child.1"      "monday.07.00.child.1"
```

(This is a random example)

I've thought about using dplyr (but I have little experience with it).

```
data <- data %>% mutate(SpentWith = case_when(
if monday.07.00.adult.1 == "yes", ~ "Adult1",
if monday.07.00.adult.2 == "yes", ~ "Adult2",
if monday.07.00.adult.3 == "yes", ~ "Adult3"
))
```

Where it would be ideal if it would add on the 'Adult1', 'Adult2', 'Adult3' strings in one character variable if it meets that condition.

Any help in any step of this process would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr and `tidyr::pivot_longer()`:

```r
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(Participant = row_number()) %>%   # add participant IDs
  pivot_longer(                            # pivot rows to columns:
    !Participant,                            ## use all columns except Participant
    names_sep = "\\.",                       ## break up column names by "."
    names_to = c("Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Adult", "SpentWith")  ## names for new cols
  ) %>% 
  filter(value == "yes") %>%              # keep "yes" values only
  group_by(Participant, Day, Hour) %>%    # within each Participant / Day / Hour:
  summarize(                              # combine SpentWith values into one string
    SpentWith = paste0("Adult", SpentWith, collapse = ", "),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  Participant Day    Hour  SpentWith             
        <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr>                 
1           1 Monday 06    Adult1, Adult2        
2           1 Monday 07    Adult1, Adult2        
3           1 Monday 08    Adult2                
4           2 Monday 06    Adult1                
5           2 Monday 07    Adult1                
6           2 Monday 08    Adult1, Adult2, Adult3
```

Comment: That works great! And thank you for the useful notes with it. Because there is a period between adult.1 and adult.2, it only returns 'adult' and I cannot see which one it is. Would it be possible to keep the period between the name and number for SpentWith? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Again, thank you so much. I've managed to fix the problem!


I've added 'Number' in the names_to() and then added them back to SpentWith with 


`unite(col=SpentWith, SpentWith, Number, na.rm=TRUE, sep=".") %>%`

Comment: @EmmaV97 nice solution! I also updated my answer to use your fixed column names, with a slightly different approach to that issue.

Comment: thank you! I have also tried your updated version of the code, but it does not work well for the complete dataset, as it then only includes Adults, but in the complete dataset, there are also columns called 'child.1, school, community' etc. But as my solution with unite() works well, I have the dataset that I wanted. Thank you so much for your help!